# Windows Phone app services

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I've released about 2 months ago an app into the Windows Phone MarketPlace and just yesterday I've released an update for the app. After the update the app seems to ask for permission to access "Location services" and "Microphone". While I understand why the app needs the location services, it's really difficult to understand the Microphone part as I'm not using the microphone anywhere... 
Could anyone give a logical explanation why such a requirement was set in the MarketPlace and if there is any way to remove it as I actually don't access the microphone in the app?

In case anyone is wondering my app is wrote for WP 7.5 as well...

Thank you in advance!

Andrei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Properties** - > **WMAppManifest.xml** -> you should unchecked "**ID_CAP_MICROPHON**" before submit your app to store .

Comment: this is the logical answer (that's why I'll mark it as answer), but not really my case :| In between updates, I didn't change the capabilities... I'll open I ticket to see what happened

Answer (score 1):

Open a support ticket and ask them why. This looks like a capabilities rebuild error.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion... will try that as I can't think of any real reason for the microphone requirement!